# Load 20 items at a time and more onScroll from a ArrayList of (unknown items) in a recyclerview

Tags: java, android-fragments, arraylist, jsoup, android-recyclerview

I am using Jsoup library to extract data from a website. I have extracted data from webpage and store in a arraylist as below.

url = "http://myagdikali.com/category/sport-news/page/";

```
private class NewsExtractor extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
String title;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { 
    Document doc = null;

            while (status == OK) {  
                currentURL = url + String.valueOf(page);
                try {

                    response = Jsoup.connect(currentURL)
                            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36")
                            .execute();
                    status = response.statusCode();
                    if (status == OK) {
                        doc = response.parse();

                        Elements Titles = doc.select("a[rel=bookmark]");

                        for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element title : Titles) {

                            String src = title.text();
                            Log.d("NEWS",src);
                            mTitles.add(src);

  }
                    }

                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
      page++;
     }
     return null
```

So what I want to do is display first 20 items at a time in recyclerview and then on scroll loading more. I don't have much idea about it. I tried but failed and sorry I have not included the code that I tried (I removed it).

Now my OnCreateView and OnPostExecute looks like this:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_all, container, false);
    int i = getArguments().getInt(NEWS);
    String topics = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.topics)[i];

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyNews);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    myRecyclerViewAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),mTitles,mDates,mLinks,mImages);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerViewAdapter);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
     }
    }
```

.............................

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    TextView text;
        text = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text11);
        text.setText("foo bar");
        myRecyclerViewAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),mTitles,mDates,mLinks,mImages);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerViewAdapter);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change onPostExecute, you are changing UI from AsyncTask

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {

getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {

    TextView text;
    text = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text11);
    text.setText("Fuck you");
    myRecyclerViewAdapter = new  MyRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),mTitles,mDates,mLinks,mImages);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerViewAdapter);
    myRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Okay @eurosecom , what's going to happen after this??

Comment: Does Recycleviewer display the items ?

Comment: With this code..no.. But When i try to extract data from page having few contents, i can extract and display the contents with same code(without  while loop)..but sometime it doesn't display items. Will this solve that problem?

Comment: I am sorry. Try add myRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

Niek Haarman has a library on Github that you might want to look into: https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations

It allows you to not only animate listview results, but it also handles displaying more items on scroll.

Comment: But I wanted to use RecyclerView. Is using library a good habit ?

Comment: In my opinion, libraries are easier to use. I always thought this one had support for the RecyclerView. Apologies for not realizing that sooner.